# Share aliased folder on Windows host with Linux Guest using VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, alias, shared-folders

I have a network drive on my Windows host that I have aliased as directory NetDir. NetDir is nested under ProjDir. I am sharing ProjDir from my Windows host to my Linux guest using VirtualBox. Non-aliased shared files are accessible on the Linux guest. Aliased NetDir appears as NetDir.lnk and contents are inaccessible. Is there a way to make NetDir.lnk accessible on the Linux guest without sharing NetDir directly?